# Python 3.4 Convert bytes literal string to bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not about decoding using UTF-8.  This is about reading a bytes object as a literal and needing it as a bytes object without reinventing the parsing process.  If there is an answer to my question out there, it is hiding behind a lot of answers to questions about decoding.

Here is what I need:

```
x = "bytearray(b'abc\xd8\xa2\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7xyz')"
y = ???(x, ???)
z = bytearray(b'abc\xd8\xa2\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7xyz')
if y == z:
   print ("Yes!")
```

Any suggestions for how to replace those question marks?

Thanks!

```
                           -- Dave
```

Comment: It might be easier to fix the code that produced the `bytearray` literal to produce something more friendly instead.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to remove all the clutter from x (`bytearray(b'` and `')`), then we just convert each character to its byte representation and wrap it into a `bytearray` object.

```
x = "bytearray(b'abc\xd8\xa2\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7xyz')"
y = bytes(ord(c) for c in x[12:-2])
```

The second approach below won't be limited to `bytearray` and you should use it with care to protect against injection, but if you are sure that your content is in the correct format you can use this:

```
x = r"bytearray(b'abc\xd8\xa2\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7xyz')"
y = eval(x)
z = bytearray(b'abc\xd8\xa2\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7xyz')
```

Here you need to prefix `x` with `r"..."` to prevent the backslashes from immediately inserting unicode sequences into x. Therefore, it might not be possible to use this with dynamic content, e.g. strings coming from standard input or read from files.

You can also use `ast.literal_eval(x[10:-1])` as suggested by kindall.

Comment: You can also let python treat slashes as literal slashes (instead of escapes) by prefixing the whole string with `r`, as in `x = r"bytearray(...)"` (r stands for "Raw" in this context)

Comment: If you chop it down to `b'...'` you can then use `ast.literal_eval()` on it to get the `bytes` object, then just call `bytearray()` on that.

Comment: The `r` is only useful if the string is coming from an actual Python string literal, and if it's coming from an actual string literal, you might as well take off the quotes and skip the whole `eval` thing entirely. If the string is coming from standard input, or a file, or a network request, or pretty much anywhere else, the `r` is unnecessary, and there'd be nowhere to put the `r` anyway.